Is x.509 bypass a security risk?
I have an embedded system that is communicating with a server using SSL over WiFi to a router and then to the internet.  I have what I've been told is the proper certificate for the server installed on the embedded side.
My messages to the server are accepted, but only if I enable x.509 bypass verification.  Without that, my messages are rejected.  Without the certificate, my messages are rejected.
My questions are:
What does x.509 bypass verification mean?  The term indicates a verification but not necessarily the bypass of the verification.  ???
Does enabling x.509 bypass verification cause any security issues, either on my side through the WiFi router, or on the server side.
Any advice is appreciated.
Dave

"I have what I've been told is the proper certificate for the server installed on the embedded side." ... what is this proper certificate? Is it issued by some widely accepted public CA, or just some random self-signed certificate created by whoever told you this? At any rate, how does this relate to Ubuntu?

There is no such thing as "x.509 bypass". What you probably mean is not validating the certificate - "x.509" meaning certificate and "bypass" meaning "not validating".  And yes, this is a security issue. The real-life equivalent is that somebody is claiming some identity (like being the president) and you are not validating the truth of this claim but simply believe it and act accordingly.

The certificate is a godaddy.com certificate.  I'll now try to figure out how to make it work.  Thanks for the advice.

I can only address things that I see in writing.  I can't say if there is or isn't a x.509 bypass.  All I can say is the SSL stack I'm using calls it a x.509 bypass.  Turning this feature on does seem to bypass SSL encryption as my communications work.
Regardless, as I understand from other comments, I now believe that this may be a security risk.  Acting with that assumption, I have implemented the correct certificates so that x.509 bypass is not needed.
Thanks.
